# How to use ComboBox as Kendo UI grid column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm working with a kendo grid and I'm trying to make Name field a combobox that has it's own datasource. I'm not getting a javascript error, but when I go to edit the name field in the grid, it is not showing a ComboBox. It still shows an input field.

```
$(function () {

    console.log("ready");

    var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "", // Returns all items
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false, visible: false },
                    Name: { type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                    Description: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true} }                        
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,
        editable: true,
        height: 400,
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", width: 200 },
            {                    
                field: "Name",
                editor: function (container, options) {     // This is where you can set other control types for the field.                                                                   
                    $('&lt; input name="' + options.field + '"/&gt;').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
                        dataSouce: [{ Id: "1", Name: "MaryMaryMary" }, { Id: "2", Name: "John"}],
                        dataValueField: "Id",
                        dataTextField: "Name",                            
                    });
                }
            }
        ],
        dataBound: function (e) {
            console.log("DataBound");
        }
    });

});
```

I'm not getting any javascript errors.

Comment: When I click edit, it doesn't give me a ComboBox in the name field. It just gives me an input box.

Comment: What happens when you type the input addition as <input instead of the &lt/gt?

Comment: @Frankie: so, Frankie, did you upgrade your version or used the hack?

Comment: @J.Bruni I actually upgraded the version. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that stinks because it was my response that suggested upgrading as compared to Bruni's to hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who "desperately" need a custom editor now and can't wait for next release, just like me... :-)

...here is my workaround... change line #12320 of **kendo.all.js** to this:

```
fields: { field: column.field, format: column.format, editor: column.editor },
```

...and voilà! Now the "editor" setting for the column makes effect!

---

I wrote the above message at http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/how-to-define-memo-style-editor-for-grid-cells.aspx#1938316

It was January 6 2012, and the current release was v2011.3.1129

Answer (score 2):

What version of KendoUI are you using? Only the recent SP1 and March beta have custom editor support: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1407/js/kendo.all.min.js

Additionally, I

1. replaced `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>`;
2. corrected the misspelled "dataSouce" property created for the KendoComboBox.

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/5fLZc) that I created that should get you going in the right direction:

Comment: I am using custom editors with older version 2011.3.1129 (with a single line of code changed)

Comment: I don't get it. Version 2011.3.1407 is an official service pack release (non-beta) for KendoUI that contains your mentioned single line of code change as well as [other improvements](http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/v1-2011-sp1-version-2011-3-1407.aspx). Why would you not just use that instead?

Comment: 1) It happened on January, before the SP release; 2) Will you pay a commercial license for me? :) I am using the Open Source license (**GPL**) - so, this is the [latest stable version](http://www.kendoui.com/account/your-products/product-versions.aspx?pid=900) I can download and use.

Comment: Since Frankie didn't specially mention it, I assumed he paid for the product (like I did). Your hack works for those using the open source version, which I'm certain will see a new version in the next week (or so).

Answer (score 1):

We have published an [example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html) showing how to do that.

Comment: This example shows grid with columns "Product Name", "Category" and "Price". But in source code I see columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Employee).ClientTemplate("#=Employee.EmployeeName#");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ShipAddress);

Answer (score 0):

I am using MVC4
In grid:

```
columns.Bound("Productname").Title("Productname")                    
   .Width(200)                                           
   .EditorTemplateName(Productname);
```

Create EditorTemplateName = Productname.
In view share:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
             .Name("Ten_dvt")
             .DataValueField("Ten_dvt")
       .DataTextField("Ten_dvt")
       .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .HighlightFirst(true)
       .DataSource(source =>
       {
           source.Read(read =>
           {
               read.Action("Dm_dvt", "Combo");
           });
       })   .Events(e => e.Select("Select_Ma_dvt").Change("Change_Ma_dvt"))
   .HeaderTemplate("<table style=\"width:100%\"><tr><td  align=\"left\"
   style=\"width:30%\">" + @Tcommont("Ma") + "</td><td align=\"left\"
   style=\"width:70%\">" + @Tcommont("Ten") + "</td></tr></table>")
        .Template("<table style=\"width:100%\"><tr><td  align=\"left\" style=\"width:30%\">" + "#: data.Ma_dvt #" + "</td><td align=\"left\"
   style=\"width:70%\">" + "#: data.Ten_dvt #" + "</td></tr></table>" +
   "<div style='width:0px; height:0px;
   overflow:hidden'>;#:data.Ma_dvt#;#:data.Ten_dvt#;</div>") )
```

Then form edit using:

```
function Change_Ma_dvt(e) {  if (this.selectedIndex == -1) {
                              var grid = $("#gridItem2").data("kendoGrid");
                              var _dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                              _dataItem.set("Ten_dvt", "");
                              _dataItem.set("Ma_dvt", "");
                          } }
```

and

```
function Select_Ma_dvt(e) {    var _Arr = e.item.text().split(";");
                          var grid = $("#gridItem2").data("kendoGrid");
                          var _dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                          _dataItem.set("Ma_dvt", _Arr[1]);
                          break; }
```

last grid show name and you choose then Id or Ma will be choose hide

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. FYI, this site tends to discourage code dumps without explanation. Adding some explanation about why this code solves the asker's problem would be useful.