# Kendo UI add DropDownList into Grid (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm Binding to a Grid class (UserId,FirstName,LastName,Choice).
Does anybody know how to put this code in a column (Choice) in a Kendo Grid in MVC 4:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("Test")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
      .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
      {
          new SelectListItem()
          {
              Text = "Option1",
              Value = "1"
          },
          new SelectListItem()
          {
              Text = "Option2",
              Value = "2"
          }
      }))
<script>
    function change() {
        var value = $("#Choice").val();
    }
</script>
```

....

```
columns.Bound(p=> p.FirsName);
columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
//How to Bind Choice???
```

I also need a text ("Option1", or "Option2") in BackEnd Code.
Any solutions?

**Edited**

I did exactly what they said:

View:

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Choice).ClientTemplate("#=Choice#");
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PopulateCategories();
        return View();
    }
```

.....

```
 private void PopulateCategories()
        {
            var dataContext = new TestDB();
            var categories = dataContext.Peoples
                .Select(c => new People()
                {
                    ChoiceID = c.ChoiceID,
                    Choice = c.Choice
                })
                .OrderBy(e => e.Choice);
            ViewData["categories"] = categories;
            ViewData["defaultCategory"] = categories.First();
        }
```

But this doesn't work...

Comment: Can you show us your controller please ? Also if this is MVC4 normally you will Option1 Text coming from the code behind.. Then through to the @Model

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559269/how-to-use-combobox-as-kendo-ui-grid-column

Comment: [the kendo sample is not compelete!your answer is in link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136786/why-the-dropdown-list-template-of-kendo-ui-sample-for-asp-net-mvc-5-dont-run-rig?noredirect=1#comment95116280_54136786)

Answer (score 0):

You just need tp take look at the documentation they provide : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

It is a custom grid so there MAY also be some JS changes involved also. You are binding from your model, and the kendo.js will look after the rest.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ClientProductViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Category).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#").Width(160);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(120);
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(90);
})
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Create();
        toolBar.Save();
    })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
        model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
        model.Field(p => p.Category).DefaultValue(
            ViewData["defaultCategory"] as Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ClientCategoryViewModel);
    })
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "Grid"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "Grid"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "Grid"))        
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "Grid"))
)
)
```

Your csHTML file needs to bind the input and passback on the trigger, whichever you are doing.

Comment: I said this to myself the same time I read that posted demo when I looked at it. where is `).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#").` defined. I imagine that it points to a stand alone kendo ddl, or am I completely wrong. Just not seeing how that little bit of code renders a ddl

Comment: The code wont render dll it will use razor syntax and iis to bind as it needs to. Its been a while since I've dealt with razor but ill go back and double check to make sure! I remember kendo was not the most user friendly with mvc if i remember correctly!

Comment: From looking at the Docs and under the HTML section it seems a little more clear as to what is going on. I know your code is straight out of the Docs and from what is given `ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#")` means nothing to me.

Comment: well the logical option is that the param from the HTML form would be this Category.CategoryName input bound from the form to the backend via HTTP.POST value at the moment im using nancy server and owin a lot more which work with posted values bounded via ajax to C# backend (to keep it as stricly typed as possible), but this would be the logical outcome.. Again will need to double check!

Comment: @Pogrindis - Im working with this same sort of issue, except that I want to update the list of items for the dropdown AFTER the grid has rendered.  The current dropdownlist is defined at the time the grid is rendered.  The template only loads once.  So how could I update this list or the template after the grid renders?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you achieve what you need -->>

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/want-to-add-dropdownlist-in-my-grid.aspx